# php regex preg_replace html tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

hello I have the following code :

```
$content = '<div class="style1" id="divelement" align="center">';
```

and here is my code :

```
preg_replace('~<div\s*.*?(?:\s*class\s*=\s*"(.*?)"\s*|\s*id\s*=\s*"(.*?)"\s*)?>~i','<div class="$1" id="$2">', $content);
```

now what I'm trying is to replace the whole  elements but keep class and id only .

Comment: Don't use regexp to parse HTML, use a DOM library like `DOMDocument`.

Comment: I have already a big file with regex only ... so I don't want to use domdocument :/

Comment: if only u can give me a regex code

Comment: Doing something the wrong way is not a good reason to continue doing something the wrong way.

Comment: [Obligatory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4639281)

Comment: DOM parsing libraries should be used for parsing DOM. RegEx is not intended to parse DOM, and should not be used to parse DOM. Please do not use RegEx to parse DOM. Instead use a DOM parser to parse DOM. Parsing DOM with RegEx has been known to open blackholes, and drive programmers to insanity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would better to use a library like `DOMDocument` to parse the HTML. But if you really have to do it with a regexp....

Don't use `|` in the regexp, that matches either `class` or `id`, but not both.

```
preg_replace('~<div\b.*?\bclass\s*=\s*"(.*?)".*?\bid\s*=\s*"(.*?)".*>~i','<div class="$1" id="$2">', $content);
```

Note that this will only work if the `class` is to the left of the `id` in the `DIV`.

Comment: Regex haters are on the prawl? :) You can replace `.*?` with `[^<]`/`[^<"]` for safer matching inside a node.